# In Mongo db I want to add an entry to a document. If the id already exists it should overwrite it, if not it should add it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use Mongo DB and node.js. Thanks for any help :).

I want to do the following:

Search for a user in the db using the googleId.

Then if the user does not have a description field yet I want to create it. Within the description field, I want to have several objects that all have the coinId as an index.

If the coinId already exists it should overwrite the content of that particular object with the variables I pass. If it does not already exist it should add the new object to the description field.

The Mongo db document should look like this in the end. Note that 1027 or 123 are the values of the coinIds.

```
googleId: "PyovWaX8HERRACmeg4IzYCaMK833"
description: 
   1027:
      _id: "ckpi7q8c60002qe9h0e4wgh3r"
      coinId: 1027
      description: "test1"
      date: 2021-06-04T10:56:52.662+00:00
   123:
      _id: "woienfeiowfnaoewinfefneo"
      coinId: 123
      description: "test2"
      date: 2021-06-04T10:56:52.662+00:00
```

I already tried the following:

```
 const { result } = await db.collection('users').updateOne(
      { googleId },
      {
        $set: {
          description: { [coinId]: { _id, coinId, description, date } },
        },
      },
      {
        returnOriginal: false,
      }
    );
```

The problem here is that the entry is always overwritten which I only want to happen if the coinId is the same.

I also tried to do it with $addToSet but then it never overwrites the object if the coinId's match.

Answer (score 0):

How about findAndModify?

[findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

In your case, something like this:

```
db.collection('users').findAndModify({
  query: { _id: googleId },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: {
          description: { [coinId]: { _id, coinId, description, date } },
        }
  },
  new: true,   // return new doc if one is upserted
  upsert: true // insert the document if it does not exist
})
```

Comment: thank you! I cannot make it work nevertheless. I'm a beginner. Can I ask, how can I test these statements? I mean in javascript I can always console log parts of a function or so. here I'm a bit lost. Also, the docs kind of suck compared to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
  query: { _id: "some potentially existing id" },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: { foo: "bar" }
  },
  new: true,   // return new doc if one is upserted
  upsert: true // insert the document if it does not exist
})
```